# File with multiple data types, into arrays, then sort one array while keeping the records together

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting

My problem is that I will be giving a file with student information: name, age, and GPA. I then have to turn each data element into a separate array. I then have to sort GPA into descending order, while keeping name and age with the corresponding GPA, and then print it out with "Name Age GPA" heading.

Comment: *My problem* - yep **your** problem - if you have a question, someone may help

Comment: @John what approach did you try and what were the issues ? if you haven't tried anything, try Comparable interface  for single way of sorting whereas Comparator interface to provide different ways of sorting, would be good if you can explain more the issues that you are facing with error.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code to sort data based on GPA. However you will have to include relevant code for file reading.

**Student.java (POJO)**

```
public class Student {    
    String name;
    int age;
    double GPA;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public double getGPA() {
        return GPA;
    }
    public void setGPA(double gPA) {
        GPA = gPA;
    }
    public Student(String name, int age, double gPA) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        GPA = gPA;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", GPA=" + GPA + "]";
    }

}
```

**StudentSorter.java**

```
 import java.util.Comparator;
    public class StudentSorter implements Comparator<Student> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {        
        if(o1.getGPA() < o2.getGPA()) return 1;
        if(o1.getGPA() > o2.getGPA()) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }   
}
```

**Tester.java**

```
    public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s1 = new Student("A",14,7.9);
        Student s2 = new Student("B",17,8.2);
        Student s3 = new Student("C",20,7.0);
        Student s4 = new Student("D",15,6.9);
        Student s5 = new Student("E",14,9.1);

        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(s1);
        list.add(s2);
        list.add(s3);
        list.add(s4);
        list.add(s5);

        StudentSorter ss = new StudentSorter();
        Collections.sort(list, ss);
        System.out.println(list.toString());        
    }
}
```